# Insufficient funds in Stripe even with funds and manual payouts enabled

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am having trouble to make `transfer` from a `paymentIntent`, I have enabled manual payouts and have funds in my test balance..
I tried also to add `source_transaction` in the transfer object, but without success

I am getting:

> StripeInvalidRequestError: Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In
> test mode, you can add funds to your available balance (bypassing your
> pending balance) by creating a charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the
> card number

I already added with this test card number..
The paymentIntent is created successfully:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
  {
    amount: amount,
    currency: "usd",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    transfer_group: "{ORDER11}",
  }
)
```

And here is my failing transfer object:

```
const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({
          amount: orderAmount,
          currency: "usd",
          destination: sellerAccountId,
          transfer_group: "{ORDER11}",
          source_transaction: pi.charges.data.id,
});
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure, was this payment intent [confirmed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm) and did does it have `status=succeeded` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status))?

You may just have a small error in your `source_transaction` which needs to be `pi.charges.data**[0]**.id`, since `data` is an array you must provide an index.